# Laravel cast model to another model when returning from database

Tags: php, laravel

**Background Information**

I have a model called **Product**. The product can have 3 different stock methods: *Serialize*, *Bulk* and *None*.

- **Serialize** is chosen when every physical item has a barcode.
- **Bulk** is chosen when we care for the changes in quantities
- **None** is chosen when we want to include a product in the inventory but we don't care about the quantity.

---

**What I want to do**

I want to create those 3 models (Serialize, Bulk, None) and extend them to the Product. Then to be able to call something like Product::all() and get a collection like this:

```php
Products [
   0   => Serialize[...]
   1   => Serialize[...]
   2   => Bulk[...]
   3   => None[...]
   ...
   500 => Bulk[...]
]
```

---

**My problem**

How can I make laravel cast each object to their respective classes automatically?

---

**Database Schema**
[image: Database Schema]

---

**My Model structure**

Product model

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The attributes that aren't mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'purchase_price' => MoneyCast::class,
        'rental_price'   => MoneyCast::class,
        'is_active'      => 'boolean',
    ];

    /**
     * Get active products only
     *
     * @param Builder $builder
     *
     * @return Builder
     */
    public function scopeActive(Builder $builder): Builder
    {
        return $builder->where('is_active', '=', true);
    }

    /**
     * Get inactive products only
     *
     * @param Builder $builder
     *
     * @return Builder
     */
    public function scopeInactive(Builder $builder): Builder
    {
        return $builder->where('is_active', '=', false);
    }

    /**
     * Set the name and slug when saving to database
     *
     * @param $value
     */
    public function setNameAttribute($value): void
    {
        $this->attributes['name'] = $value;
        $this->attributes['slug'] = Str::slug($value);
    }

    /**
     * Get the products full name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFullNameAttribute(): string
    {
        return $this->details
            ? "{$this->name} {$this->details}"
            : $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Calculate total stocks
     *
     * @return int
     */
    abstract public function getTotalAttribute(): int;

    /**
     * Calculate total stocks in quarantine
     *
     * @return int
     */
    abstract public function getQuarantinedAttribute(): int;

    /**
     * Calculate available stocks
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getAvailableAttribute(): int
    {
        return $this->getTotalAttribute() - $this->getQuarantinedAttribute();
    }

    /**
     * Get brand
     *
     * @return BelongsTo
     */
    public function brand(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get category
     *
     * @return BelongsTo
     */
    public function category(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
```

Serialize Model

```php
class Serialize extends Product
{
/**
     * Calculate total stocks
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getTotalAttribute(): int
    {
        return $this->stocks()->count();
    }

    /**
     * Calculate total stocks in quarantine
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getQuarantinedAttribute(): int
    {
        return $this->stocks->sum(function ($stock) {
            return $stock->repairs()
                         ->where('status', '!=', last(Repair::STATUSES))
                         ->where('is_working', '=', false)
                         ->count();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Get associated stocks
     *
     * @return HasMany
     */
    public function stocks(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Stock::class)->orderBy('barcode');
    }
}
```

Bulk Model

```php
class Bulk extends Product
{
    /**
     * Calculate total stocks
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getTotalAttribute(): int
    {
        return $this->transactions()->sum('quantity');
    }

    /**
     * Calculate total stocks in quarantine
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getQuarantinedAttribute(): int
    {
        return $this->stocks->sum(function ($stock) {
            return $stock->repairs()
                         ->where('status', '!=', last(Repair::STATUSES))
                         ->where('is_working', '=', false)
                         ->sum('quantity');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Get bulk stock transactions.
     *
     * @return HasMany
     */
    public function transactions(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class)->latest();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can return a new instance of those sub-types based on the stock method:

```
Product::all()
  ->map(function($product) {
       switch( $product->stock_method ) {
           case 'Serialize':
               return new Serialize((array) $product);
           case 'Bulk':
               return new Bulk((array) $product);
           // and so on..
       }
       return $product;
  });
```

You can also override the `get` method to not have to write this piece of code on every `all`

```
class Product extends Model {
    // static method 'all' calls 'get' defined in Illuminate\Database\EloquentBuilder
    public function get($columns = ['*']) {
        return parent::get($columns)
            ->map(function($product) {
               switch( $product->stock_method ) {
                 case 'Serialize':
                   return new Serialize((array) $product);
                 case 'Bulk':
                   return new Bulk((array) $product);
                 // and so on..
              }
             return $product;
            });
    }
```

Comment: Yes! That is one way of doing what I want but the problem is that I will have to add that piece everywhere I call Products. I'm looking for a way for laravel to do it automatically. So that I can also use Route model binding.

Comment: @Jose I guess you could override the `all` or `get` method and have it return this piece of code

Comment: didnt know ->map() able to use together with eloquent. Thanks for your input !

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically it's very hard, if not impossible, to cast a parent object to a child object.

Since you are selecting `all()` products, you could also create 3 separate queries for all 3 product types, where each query has the right conditions, like checking for barcode in the case you mention.

Each query could be fast, of indexes are setup correctly.

For each query you get a collection, so you end up with 3 separate collections. A simple `concat()` gives you the resulting collection you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Hook into `newCollection()` on Product model:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function newCollection(array $models = Array())
    {
        // Casting if statements here...
        $casted = $models;

        // then return a collection
        return collect($casted);

        // or maybe even create a custom collection
        return new ProductCollection($casted);

        // Dummy example (run Product::all() to see results)
        return collect([1,2,3]);
    }
}
```

Great article: https://heera.it/extend-laravel-eloquent-collection-object

Edit: I see now you need unique relationship methods - that will probably not work with this solution.